# Is it possible to force a key frame 2 seconds after the time of the last key frame by using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I know that prev_forced_t returns time of the last **forced** key frame. But I need something that return time of the last key frame (not forced but any).
This parameter will work only with forced frames:
`-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,prev_forced_t+2)"`
I need something like:
`-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,${LAST_KEY_FRAME_T}+2)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `force_key_frames` `expr` doesn't expose the time of the last non-forced key frame, according to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

You can either modify the `ffmpeg` source code or use the libs to achieve your goal or you can try doing it in two passes using `ffprobe` to get the keyframe timestamps information first:

`ffprobe -select_streams v -show_entries frame=key_frame,pkt_pts_time <input> | grep key_frame=1 -A1`

You can force keyframes at specific times using `-force_key_frames[:stream_specifier] time[,time...]`

This may not be feasible due to potential command length.